# Parse wrong property value from object type have property null value to IAcctionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a model like this:

```
 public class ObjectA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public object OtherData { get; set; }
    }
```

And the JSON data for the same:

```
 {
        "id" : 12 ,
        "name": "Ababa",
        "description": "data Des",
        "otherData": {
          "signTime":null,
          "objectId":129,
          "confirmStatus": null,
          "note": "nothing"
        }
    }
```

I receive this data and using JsonConvert.Deserializer by  Newtonsoft.Json provider parse this JSON content to my object, but after I return data type IAcctionResult at controller values of them, it has become like this:

```
 {
        "id" : 12 ,
        "name": "Ababa",
        "description": "data Des",
        "otherData": {
          "signTime":[],
          "objectId":[],
          "confirmStatus": [],
          "note": []
        }
    }
```

Where was my code wrong?

My result is expected to receive JSON data (not the way using parse otherData to a string).

Comment: Both answers were probably generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar).

Comment: This question is close to incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77414054/edit) it?